# Can I run Zend Server along with already-installed LAMP Stack?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, lamp, zend

I already have Apache2+MySQL+PHP installed and am using it on Ubuntu Linux.

I would like to test out the Zend Framework installation bundled with Zend Server, since the server is supposed to be optimized for the framework. But I don't want it to change the way my current testing sites function.

Can I have Zend Server run concurrently with my current sites without changing their PHP/Apache/MySQL settings?

Comment: I dont really know the answer but...i am in your exactly same situation, and a few minutes ago i tried to install ZS; everything went ok but when i ran it entering the address http://localhost:10081/ZendServer into the web browser it showed me an error;
i think this is due to an imperfect configuration of hosts in the machine as LAMPP is mapped to localhost, and ZS should be mapped to something else (in stead of localhost:10081, cause localhost is reserved for apache), so im thinkink about editing the hosts file in /etc to obtain a workaround. lets see what happens :)

Comment: I don't even know if it makes sense to have two webservers running on a single computer. I think it would theoretically possible but you'd probably have to do some tricky stuff to send traffic to the right one. I think perhaps the reason I've gotten no answers is because the question is either A.) retarded or B.) way too hard (or both).